# Trying to make a function which squares all values in an array. Getting strange number on the last value

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, variables

```
int squaring_function (int *array, int i);

int main()
{
    int array[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0; (i <= 5) ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        printf("\nArray value %d is %d",i,array[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; (i <= 5) ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (squaring_function(array, i));
        printf("\nSquared array value %d is %d",i,array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int squaring_function (int *array, int i)
{
    return pow((array[i]),2);
}
```

I'm trying to use this squaring_function to square each value in turn in my array (containing integers 0 to 5). It seems to work however the last value (which should be 5)^2 is not coming up as 25. [cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxWv6.png)
I have tried reducing the array size to 5 (so the last value is 4) however this prints an incorrect number also.
I'm quite new to C and don't understand why this last value is failing.

I'm aware I could do this without a separate function however I'd quite like to learn why this isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: `int array[5];` has elements `0, 1, 2, 3, and 4` all `5` of those indexes, but there's no element `5` cause that would be 6...

Comment: Out of bounds access, undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, don't waste time and code using pow(), that does conversions from int to double and back, plus function call overhead. array[i] * array[i] is 100 times faster and produces smaller, simpler code.

Comment: As [many] others have pointed out, you're exceeding the bounds of your array. Given `int array[5];`, the [corrected] `for` loop _can_ be done as `for (i = 0;  i <= 4;  ++i)` but it is much more idiomatic [and easier] to do `for (i = 0;  i < 5;  ++i)` because you just plug in the _same_ number in the two places.

Comment: Output newlines at the end of the message rather than at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *2* bugs in your code. First is that you're accessing array out of bounds. The memory rule is that with `n` elements the indices must be *smaller than n*, hence `< 5`, not `<= 5`. And if you want to count up to 5, then you must declare

```
int array[6];
```

---

The *other* problem is that your code calculates `pow(5, 2)` as 24.99999999 which gets truncated to 24. The number 24 went to the memory location immediately after `array` overwriting `i`; which then lead to `array[i]` evaluating to `array[24]` which happened to be all zeroes.

Use `array[i] * array[i]` instead of `pow` to ensure that the calculation is done with integers.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
int array[5];
for(int i=0; (i <= 5) ; i++)
```

exceeds array bounds and introduces undefined behaviour. Note that `0..5` are actually 6 values, not 5. If you though see some "meaningful" output, well - good or bad luck - it's just the result of undefined behaviour, which can be everything (including sometimes meaningful values).

Answer (score 1):

Your array isn't big enough to hold all the values.

An array of size 5 has indexes from 0 - 4.  So `array[5]` is off the end of the array.  Reading or writing past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Increase the size of the array to 6 to fit the values you want.

```
int array[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show the flaws in the posted code.
If your goal is to square each element of an array, you can either write a function which square a value

```
void square(int *x)
{
    *x *= *x;
}
```

and apply it to every element of an array or write a function which takes an entire array as an input and perform that transformation:

```
void square_array(int size, int arr[size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] *= arr[i];
    }
}
// ... where given an array like
int nums[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// you can call it like this
square_array(5, nums); // -> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
```